# SQL: Count on different where case with a single query

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, I have a table recording user activities of viewing and downloading files,

```
file_id    user    activity
      2     Tim        view
      1     Ron        view
      1     Ron        view
      2     Tim    download
      2     Ron        view
      1     Ron        view
      2     Ron    download
```

The ideal select result is like this,

```
file_id    viewed_by    views    downloaded_by    downloads
      1            1        3                0            0
      2            2        2                2            2
```

What I can do is getting views data and downloads data in 2 independent queries,

```
COUNT(*), COUNT(DISTINCT user)
FROM table
WHERE activity = 'view'
GROUP BY file_id

(and then do another query for downloads)
```

Is it possible to do this in a single query or with a subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and use conditional aggregation to only count rows, where the activity matches either views or downloads using `CASE` expressions.

```
SELECT file_id,
       count(DISTINCT CASE activity
                        WHEN 'view' THEN
                          user
                      END) viewed_by,
       count(CASE activity
               WHEN 'view' THEN
                 user
             END) views,
       count(DISTINCT CASE activity
                        WHEN 'download' THEN
                          user
                      END) downloaded_by,
       count(CASE activity
               WHEN 'download' THEN
                 user
             END) downloads
       FROM elbat
       GROUP BY file_id;
```